# Modifying elements of a binary tree c++

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I have a problem concerning modifying the elements of a binary tree. This is the error I get:
Access violation reading location 0x00000018.
I think I'm accessing a null pointer but I don't know how to solve the problem.

This is the code that I used:

```
void modifyStatus(nod* root)
{

if (root->info.st == done)
    root->info.st = reachedDest;
    modifyStatus(root->st);
    modifySatus(root->dr);
}
```

I must specify that "done" and "reachedDest" are the elements of an enum.

Comment: Have you checked if `root` is `nullptr`? How about `root->st`?

Comment: that doesn look like a binary tree.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to check if the root is NULL.

Answer (score 1):

> I think I'm accessing a null pointer but I don't know how to solve the problem.

Check the pointer for `NULL` before accessing it:

```
void modifyStatus(nod* root) {
    if (!root) {
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Note that calls that look like this `modifySatus(root->st);` look like C, not like C++. In situations when you have control over `nod` class, you should consider making `modifySatus` a member function:

```
root->modifyStatus();
```